# How can I get atom.io's "Go to Declaration" to really do that?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

In atom.io, if I right click in "wrappedlabel" here:

```
<label class="wrappedlabel">"Be Kind to Animammals - Kiss a Duckbilled Platypus Today"</label>
```

...it teases me with "*Go to Declaration*"

Clicking does not take me to that class in the .css file in the project.

Is there a way to get this to actually work? If so, it would be an even sweeter suite. Having it tell me "Go to Declaration" and then leaving me hanging is better than telling me to "go to" [somewhere else], but still...

Comment: ctags worked for me after symbol-gen

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Go to declaration" works with symbols used in your project.

The feature requires ctags which need to be generated per project. This can be achieved with the command line or with an atom plugin (https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) .

You can follow [this](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/issues/9) issue on github for further details

Comment: this package let's you generate ctags for your project: https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen

Comment: I used the package, tags seems correctly generated but still no success.

Comment: symbol-gen spawns a 100% cpu ctags-darwin process every time I save, even in the same file.  try https://atom.io/packages/atom-ctags instead if you're hitting this issue too.  It lets you keystroke-click keywords like atom-autocomplete-php and autocomplete-php, which I've disabled.  Just look in its settings for keystroke options and file patterns that you can exclude from indexing.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon On Linux, on  project folder with `ctags -R .` from [exuberant-ctags](https://ctags.io/) package. If anyone try and dismiss atom-ctags remember to re-enable symbol-view.

Comment: worked for me - thank you! you can find the command or trigger it under 'Packages > Symbols > Generate for Project' - The Statusbar shows "Generating Symbols" once this Message disappears it works :)

Answer (score 15):

- In a terminal run

  ```
  apm install atom-ctags
  ```
- Restart atom (sometimes twice)
- Open a file in your project
- Context menu - rebuild ctags
- Go to declaration should now work for most places

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to install atom-ctags from inside Atom Preferences (not the terminal) before "rebuild ctags" was in the context menu.  Also probably had to restart Atom more than twice.

Comment: Worked. Tried this answer because it has step-by-step to follow instead of general instructions that lets newbies with more questions (how to get ctags by command line or how to install a plugin in atom).

Comment: To find "rebuild ctags", just right click in a file.