# Atom - IDE package - Find References not working (PHP)

Tags: php, ide, atom-editor

1. I have Atom editor installed (Version 1.37.0)
2. Installed the package [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)
3. Installed the package [ide-php](https://atom.io/packages/ide-php)

Now I go into my PHP file and make right-click on a class and chose "Find References"

```
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
```

Instead of opening a panel/window and displaying references, Atom shows a warning popup with this message:

> Find References: Symbol references are not available for this project.

The only suggestion I found fixing this is by installing the ide-php package, what I already did. Restarted Atom results with same warning message displayed.

Any ideas how to get "Show References" running?

Comment: Hmmm, from devtools console, can you enable debugging with atom.config.set('core.debugLSP', true) and share what you see when trying Find References?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my notebook did the trick. I probably didn't restart Atom properly to make the new packages work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

If you want to make `Go to Declaration` work you haver to generate symbols first: [here how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083136/how-can-i-get-atom-ios-go-to-declaration-to-really-do-that).